# Restsharp: IRestResponse content returns "[]"

Tags: c#, rest, unit-testing, client, restsharp

I am trying to implement a test of my rest api using restsharp, which seems to be a very powerful and easy tool to use for simple tests.

With that said I still have problems getting content from my IRestResponse.

The code goes as following:

```
...
    [TestMethod]
    public void Testing_Whether_Get_Returns_cellphone()
    {
        // Arrange
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://pseudoUrl/Users?UserId={uid}");       
        //restClient.AddDefaultHeader("headerType1", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        //restClient.AddDefaultUrlSegment("uid", "25248896");
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        restRequest.AddQueryParameter("uid", "25248896");
        restRequest.AddHeader("headerType1", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        // Act
        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest); // restresponse = "StatusCode: Ok.."
        string response = restResponse.Content; // response = "[]"

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(response.Contains("cellphone"));
    }
...
```

When testing the above, the statuscode is 200, but content is "[]", even though that when I test it with swagger, I get a nice json-response filled with the wanted content.

As you can see I have tried using both AddDefaultUrlSegment and AddQueryParameter. The last one is the most obvious, I guess?

the following url in swagger is: "http://pseudoUrl/Users?UserId=25248896" added the header: headerType1 and again - that works perfectly fine.

Can anyone see, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why yor not buiid the url with the parameter value? `RestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://pseudoUrl/Users?UserId=25248896");`

Comment: @juanpe that will give me a content, yes, but why doesn't the above work? Should I not be able to change the query parameter? `http://pseudoUrl/Users?UserId=uid` wont fix it, but `http://pseudoUrl/Users?UserId=25248896` will, which I dont get.

Comment: Whith `restRequest.AddQueryParameter("uid", "25248896");`you are added a new param named "uid"

Comment: @juanpe the correct answer is stated by 'A Friend'. Your first comment is a way to do it, but the other answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddQueryParameter` with your current inputs is going to add `?uid=25248896` to the URL.

Just put your URL without query `http://pseudoUrl/Users` into the `RestClient` constructor and then change the "uid" to "UserId" in `AddQueryParameter`

```
[TestMethod]
public void Testing_Whether_Get_Returns_cellphone()
{
    // Arrange
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://pseudoUrl/Users");
    RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    restRequest.AddQueryParameter("UserId", "25248896");
    restRequest.AddHeader("headerType1", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    // Act
    IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest); 
    string response = restResponse.Content; // response = "[]"

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response.Contains("cellphone"));
}
```

Comment: @A Friend YOU sir, deserve to rule the 7 kingdoms! Thank you very much for stating out the obvious.